# React, Typescript, and Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I am trying to write component that calls a webservice and returns some data asynchronously through a promise. once this promise is resolved, i would like to include the results in my component's render method. Ideally i think i would like the results of the promise to be passed into another component. IE; the result of the promise is a list of items.

One more thing - i am writing this React component using Typescript.

Currently i have the following code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let fooProps = listGetter.returnListData().then((response) => {
        return response;
    });
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    <div>
        <Foo ElementProperties={this.fooProps} />
    </div>
}
```

However, this code errors out and displays "cannot assign null value to property".

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to handle promise's and resolve them into components in REACT?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if your returned list is empty/null in your then callback. Also, your fooProps is block scoped, so your render function can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [the state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) of the component.
Changing the state results in a re-rendering of the component, much like how when a component changes the properties of a child results in the child being re-rendered.

Something like:

```
componentWillMount() {
    listGetter.returnListData().then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            fooProps: response.fooProps
        });
    });
}

public render(): JSX.Element {
    <div>
        <Foo ElementProperties={ this.state.fooProps } />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nitzan. This is exactly what i was looking for. I hadnt checked for null and before the response was returned the render method began executing passing a null into the Foo control and rendering a null reference except. I reworked it and bound the state to the function and its working quite well now.

Answer (score 0):

Promises never return their values, they only return a `Thenable` so you can chain them. The return value you're looking for will be in the first argument of the function passed to `then`

```
componentWillMount() {
    // bind the function to `this` so even if you don't use an
    // anonymous arrow function this call will work in the right context
    let updateComponent = this.updateComponent.bind(this);
    listGetter.returnListData().then((res) => {
        updateComponent(res);
    })
}

updateComponent(res) {
    this.setState({fooProps: res.fooProps})
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `bind` here as the arrow function keeps the scope of `this`.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I've just added a comment, of course it's not needed, but it's a good thing to get used to, especially if you use different function syntaxes. I'd maybe even recommend `this.updateComponent = this.updateComponent.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: It's redundant and creates a new function for no reason